# How to create a .Net version 2.0 website using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have created a website using Visual Studio 2012. It is working just fine. The problem is I have to deploy it on a server that has .Net Framework 2.0 only. So I created another website using Visual Studio 2012 and set its version to 2.0. After copying the code of  just a single page I tried to run it. But I am getting the errors "Unknown server tag asp:ScriptManager" and "Unknown server tag asp:UpdatePanel". I need them both as I have to use  PageMethods in my page. How can I create a .Net Framework 2.0 website with ScriptManager and UpdatePanel without any error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ScriptManager and UpdatePanel are available in .NET 3.5 and above only.

Comment: But same server is running websites with ScriptManager and UpdatePanel. How then they have been configured. Can't I use ScriptManager and UpdatePanel with .Net Framework 2.0?

Comment: I linked the MSDN documentation in my answer, you will see that they aren't present in framework 2.0. Are you sure that these WebSites are hosted as .Net 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to install [ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883) if you are planning to use scriptmanager and update panel in .NET 2.0. Prior to .NET 3.5, Ajax was available as a separate library.

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh. I have downloaded the Ajax Extensions and it worked on my local machine. I am about to deploy the website. Will tell you shortly. Thanks.

Comment: After uploading the new application I get the following error: Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'CamWebApplication1' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: @user1640256 I assume that 'CamWebApplication1' is one of your projects. Follow the instructions I gave you and change the project settings to target framework 2.0. Then, update your references if needed.

Comment: Hi Luke, I did follow the instructions. First I downloaded the ScriptManager Extensions and installed it. Then I opened Visual Studio and changed the properties of the project. I changed the target framework to 2.0. It closed and reopened the solution. I could also see Ajax Extensions in the toolbox. Also, the project is working fine on my local machine. I am getting the error only when I copied the whole contents to the web application folder. I think the problem is with config file or IIS. I am looking into it.

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh and Luke. It is working just fine. It was configuration error from IIS part. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't have to recreate your project. Go to the project settings, application, then change the "Target Framework".

To clearly answer your question, the answer is : you can't.

As Jamie Keeling suggested, [Script Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) and [Update Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) came with .Net Framework version 3.5.

You will have to find other components or some kind of workaround.

Comment: @user1640256 You should still take a look at bhavesh lad's link. I don't know this and it may solve your problems. Don't forget to tell us if it works :)

Comment: Yes Luke. I have downloaded the Ajax Extensions and it worked on my local machine. I am about to deploy the website. Will tell you shortly.